# Gerar um xml em c#

Tags: c#

Preciso criar uma aplicação, onde os dados serão salvos em um xml local e depois sera enviado para um servidor usando um wcf. Porem estou com a seguinte duvida o que eu faço no cliente e o que eu faço no serviço (wcf). Sou novo nessa area e não faço ideia de por onde começo alguem poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer?

Answer (score 6):

Dá pra fazer com LINQ to XML, é bem simples.
Fiz um exemplo bem basicão pra ficar fácil de entender:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }

    public Pessoa(string nome, int idade)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Idade = idade;
    }
}

public static void Escrever()
{
    var pessoas = new[] { new Pessoa("Fulano", 10), new Pessoa("Ciclano", 20) };

    var xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Pessoas",
                                        pessoas.Select(p => new XElement("Pessoa",
                                            new XAttribute("Nome", p.Nome),
                                            new XAttribute("Idade", p.Idade)))));
    xml.Save("pessoas.xml");
}

public static void Ler()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load("pessoas.xml");

    Pessoa[] pessoas = xml.Element("Pessoas").Elements("Pessoa")
                       .Select(x => new Pessoa(x.Attribute("Nome").Value,
                                               int.Parse(x.Attribute("Idade").Value))).ToArray();
}
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pessoas>
  <Pessoa Nome="Fulano" Idade="10" />
  <Pessoa Nome="Ciclano" Idade="20" />
</Pessoas>
```

Segue um link do site do Macoratti mais aprofundado: http://www.macoratti.net/09/02/lnq_xml1.htm

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando o modelo do vitor, você também pode utilizar a classe atributo `Serializable`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public Pessoa()
    {

    }
    public Pessoa(string nome, int idade)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Idade = idade;
    }


    public static void Escrever()
    {
        Pessoa[] pessoas = new[] { new Pessoa("Fulano", 10), new Pessoa("Ciclano", 20) };

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa[]));

        using (System.IO.TextWriter Write = new System.IO.StreamWriter("pessoas.xml", true))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(Write, pessoas);
            Write.Close();
        }
    }

    public static Pessoa Ler()
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));
        Pessoa pessoas = null;
        using (System.IO.TextReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("pessoas.xml"))
        {
            pessoas = Serializer.Deserialize(Reader) as Pessoa;
            Reader.Close();
        }

        return pessoas;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O que você quer é um ambiente de banco de dados, *in loco*, para trabalhar com seu app em modo *off-line* e, quando tiver uma conexão, sincronizar esses dados. Certo?

Bom, como não foi dito se é um app desktop ou mobile, ou partir do princípio que está usando .NET Framework *full*, ou seja, um app desktop.

Para esses caso, exclusivamente, eu recomendo usar [System.Data.DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset). DataSet é uma representação, me memória, de um banco de dados. Com ele você pode simular todo um banco de dados, criando tabelas, fazendo relacionamento, até mesmo controlar transação.

Mas a *feature* mais importante no seu caso é que ela possui já métodos para gravar e recuperar informações em XML. Veja:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Tabela1"));
dataSet.WriteXml(@"c:\bancodedados.xml");
```

Seu cenário cabe muito bem usar esse cara. É super fácil de implementar, e já possui também recursos para salvar e recuperar dados locais em XML.

Porém, atente-se que não é recomendado - por mim, pelo menos - a usar este cara em qualquer cenário. No seu, especificamente, cabe.

Uns meses atrás eu escrevi um artigo desencorajando a usarem por sua complexidade. Falando sobre os [males do DataSet e DataTable](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/). Vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Então,  tenho uma aplicação(desktop)  onde o client vai retornar um objeto.  Ai no serviço (wcf) tenho que criar um xml onde sera salvo esse objeto.  O xml tem q ser criado e salvo na maquina, e depois  que for gerado, usando uma procedure enviar para o banco de dados. Nao posso salvar em memória, pois depois vou ter vários usuários usando essa aplicação e mando os dados para o xml e salvando no servidor.

Comment: @Luciano, não entendi pq não manter em memoria já que o XML será gerado no serviço de WCF. Joga o XML em Cache e distribui entre os usuários. Salvar dados no disco da aplicação é um péssima prática.