# Dica de Construção de arquivo XML usando xml Serializer - Forma mais eficiente

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Estou montando um arquivo XML cuja estrutura deve ser possuir tags aninhadas conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima é a saída para o código que se segue abaixo:

```
public class Feeder
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double VMin { get; set; }
   public double VNom { get; set; }
   public double VMax { get; set; }
   public double FPMin { get; set; }
}

public class FeedersLimit
{
   public Feeder feederBase; //Classe Feeder é um atributo
}

public class FinancialLimite
{
    public int HorizonPlan { get; set; }
    public int Wacc { get; set; }
}

public class EngineerRules
{
    public int VarTensMax { get; set; }
}

// Classe FeederLimite, FinancialLimte e EnginnerRules são atributos dessa Classe

public class ConfigurationStudy
{
    public FeedersLimit feederLimit;
    public FinancialLimite financialLimite;
    public EngineerRules enginnerRules;
}
```

E o código responsável por gerar meu XML é o que está abaixo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ConfigurationStudy config = new ConfigurationStudy();
        config.feederLimit = new FeedersLimit();
        config.financialLimite = new FinancialLimite();
        config.enginnerRules = new EngineerRules();
        config.feederLimit.feederBase = new Feeder();

        //Setando valores para FeederBase
        config.feederLimit.feederBase.Name = "CJB-F2";
        config.feederLimit.feederBase.VMin = 0.93;
        config.feederLimit.feederBase.VNom = 13.8;
        config.feederLimit.feederBase.VMax = 1.05;
        config.feederLimit.feederBase.FPMin = 0.92;

        //Setando Valores para FinancialLimite
        config.financialLimite.HorizonPlan = 5;
        config.financialLimite.Wacc = 2;

        //Setando valores para EnginnerRules
        config.enginnerRules.VarTensMax = 5;

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationStudy));
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("EstudoAlocacao.xml");

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, config);
        streamWriter.Close();

        FileStream meuFileStream = new FileStream("EstudoAlocacao.xml", FileMode.Open);

        ConfigurationStudy _config = (ConfigurationStudy)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(meuFileStream);

        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase.VMin);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase.VNom);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase.VMax);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.feederLimit.feederBase.FPMin);

        Console.WriteLine(_config.financialLimite);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.financialLimite.HorizonPlan);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.financialLimite.Wacc);

        Console.WriteLine(_config.enginnerRules);
        Console.WriteLine(_config.enginnerRules.VarTensMax);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Embora essa forma de construção do meu XML **funcione**, acredito que ela não seja a forma mais eficiente de se fazer. Pois terei muitas tags aninhadas, e o tamanho do XML que preciso gerar é relativamente grande.

Minha questão é:

1. Existe uma maneira mais fácil de construir meu XML seguindo a estrutura proposta? **Lembrando que não posso mudar minha estrutura**
2. Alguma dica de estruturação de código?

Answer (score 0):

Já que você está utilizando o `XmlSerializer` e quer diminuir o tamanho dos arquivos gerados, minha sugestão é marcar, nas suas classes, as propriedades de tipos primitivos (`double`, `string`, `int`, etc.) com o atributo `[XmlAttribute]`.

Elas ficariam dessa forma:

```
public class Feeder
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double VMin { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double VNom { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double VMax { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double FPMin { get; set; }
}

public class FeedersLimit
{
    public Feeder feederBase;
}

public class FinancialLimite
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int HorizonPlan { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Wacc { get; set; }
}

public class EngineerRules
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int VarTensMax { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationStudy
{
    public FeedersLimit feederLimit;
    public FinancialLimite financialLimite;
    public EngineerRules enginnerRules;
}
```

Assim, quando essas propriedades são serializadas, elas formam **atributos** no XML ao invés de **elementos**. O tamanho do arquivo é reduzido e seu conteúdo fica até mais legível, na minha opinião:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationStudy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <feederLimit>
    <feederBase Name="CJB-F2" VMin="0.93" VNom="13.8" VMax="1.05" FPMin="0.92" />
  </feederLimit>
  <financialLimite HorizonPlan="5" Wacc="2" />
  <enginnerRules VarTensMax="5" />
</ConfigurationStudy>
```

Agora, caso você não tenha acesso ao código das classes, ou elas façam parte de uma biblioteca externa ou qualquer outro motivo, dá pra fazer com LINQ também. [Veja essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126527/gerar-um-xml-em-c/126650#126650).